# BeautifulSoup find.text returns empty string although element exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, espn

I am scraping the following; https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/ and trying to get the times of the games

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for section in soup.find_all("section", {"class": "Card gameModules"}):
    for game in section.find_all("section", {"class": "Scoreboard bg-clr-white flex flex-auto justify-between"}):
        print(game.find("div", {"class": "ScoreCell__Time ScoreboardScoreCell__Time h9 clr-gray-03"}).text)
```

Even though it should return the times of the games, it just returns empty strings. Why is this?

Comment: That content is most likely to be dynamically loaded with javascript. In that case `reuqests` can't see it. Test it by reviewing the output of `print(r.convent)` or by accessing the page with javascript disabled in the browser.

Comment: Go bring up that web page.  Now do Ctrl-U to "View Page Source".  THAT'S what `requests` sees.  It has templates to fill in, but none of the data.  The data is supplied later via Javascript.

Comment: Are you sure the `div` you're looking for exists ? Can you save the div you are calling a `find` on and paste the output of `div.prettify()`

Comment: [Canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

Your html class element selection `ScoreCell__Time ScoreboardScoreCell__Time h9 clr-gray-03` is correct but empty that's why you are getting empty ResultSet. Select the right content related to the element, then you will get output:

**Example:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for section in soup.find_all("section", {"class": "Card gameModules"}):
    for game in section.find_all("section", {"class": "Scoreboard bg-clr-white flex flex-auto justify-between"}):
        print(game.find("div", {"class": "ScoreCell__TeamName ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName truncate db"}).text)
```

**Output:**

```
Jaguars
Bills
Saints
Texans
Seahawks
Giants
Bengals
Lions
Falcons
Commanders
Eagles
Raiders
Packers
Broncos
Buccaneers
Chargers
```